# how can I remove the outer rectangle and remain the inner square?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A rectangle and a square appeared when I used the command `\draw[clip]`, but I only need the inner square. What should I do to remove the outer rectangle? When I used `\path`, both rectangle and square disappeared.
[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
    tmargin=2cm,%
    rmargin=2cm,%
    bmargin=2cm,%
    lmargin=2cm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

% only used for the example
\newlength{\skiplength}
\setlength{\skiplength}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\skiplength}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\centering{
A1\\
\vspace{\skiplength}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=11.1cm, y=7.5cm]
    \draw [clip=true model=individual] (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle
         (2cm, 0.5cm)
        [rounded corners=5pt] -- (2cm, 2.5cm)
        [rounded corners=10pt] -- (4cm, 2.5cm)
        [rounded corners=0.5cm] -- (4cm, 0.5cm)
        [sharp corners] -- cycle;

    \node[anchor=south west,%
        inner sep=0,%
        outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics{a1_03}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Something wrong happened to your code, all `[` and `]` has been replaced by `\[` and `\]`, would you mind fixing that?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't fix the one thing I actually suggested you fix. For example, you  have `\documentclass\[ ... \]{article}`, which should be `\documentclass[...]{article}`, and same for all the other `[` and `]` it seems. (This happens occasionally, don't know why. I assume those backslashes are not there in your `.tex` file)

Comment: thank you, I don't know where these codes come from.

Comment: off-topic, but `\centering` does not take arguments, so it should be `\centering A1` and not `\centering{ A1`

Comment: Can you please also fix all the other `\[...\]`?

Comment: It happens sometimes, as I said I don't know why, a bug of the site itself probably. I also said it happened for *all* `[` and `]`, not just the first one.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there were so many errors, I thought there was only one this type error.

Comment: By the way, I think I figured out why you got all those extra backslashes: you inserted an image with the code still selected. If you paste in some code, select it and hit the `{}` button, it is highlighted as code. If you then immediately clicks the button to insert in image (*without* first deselecting the code), the brackets are escaped with backslashes, probably because they're used in the Markdown for inserting images. So not really a bug, just user error: always deselect the code block before you insert an image.

Comment: you are right.  I also think so.

Answer (score 3):

> based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290508/36296

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
    tmargin=2cm,%
    rmargin=2cm,%
    bmargin=2cm,%
    lmargin=2cm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

% only used for the example
\newlength{\skiplength}
\setlength{\skiplength}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\skiplength}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\tikzset{
    clip even odd rule/.code={\pgfseteorule}, % Credit to Andrew Stacey 
  invclip/.style = {
    clip,
    insert path = [clip even odd rule]{
        [reset cm](-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)rectangle(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\centering{
A1\\
\vspace{\skiplength}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=11.1cm, y=7.5cm]
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}        \clip[invclip] (2cm, 2.5cm)  [rounded corners=5pt]  -- (4cm, 2.5cm) -- (4cm, 0.5cm) -- (2cm, 0.5cm) -- (2cm, 2.5cm) [sharp corners] --  cycle;
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[anchor=south west,%
        inner sep=0,%
        outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}};
        \draw[red, line width = 4pt] (2.1cm, 2.5cm)  [rounded corners=5pt]  -- (4cm, 2.5cm) -- (4cm, 0.5cm) -- (2cm, 0.5cm) -- (2.cm, 2.5cm) [sharp corners] --  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need the lines of the inner square , your code has the same effect with \path.

Comment: @dozer And if you would just repeat the path with `\draw`?

Comment: Thank you. But I need the inner square exactly the same with the clip, because I will use it as a option to choose.